# Delegation in WCF web service

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, active-directory, xbap

I have a WCF web service, currently served over WSHttpBinding endpoint with Transport security and Windows client credential type. The service is hosted on top of IIS 5.1 with SSL configured using a certificate from the domain certificate authority. IIS itself runs with the identity of test@domain.com on a domain computer. Anonymous access is disabled and Integrated Windows Authentication is the only way to authenticate.

The service has a method which returns the current windows identity name and impersonation level. The method has Impersonation set to Required in its OperationBehaviourAttribute.

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
public IEnumerable<string> GetInformation()
{
    WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    return new List<string>()
    {
        identity.Name,
        identity.ImpersonationLevel.ToString()
    };
}
```

I'm building the WCF Channel manually in the client and allowing the delegation for the service.

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
    HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

EndpointAddress endpoint =
    new EndpointAddress("https://host/DelegateService/Service.svc");

ChannelFactory<ServiceInterface.IService> cf =
    new ChannelFactory<ServiceInterface.IService>(binding, endpoint);

cf.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
    TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;

ServiceInterface.IService service = cf.CreateChannel();
```

The client is a fully trusted XBAP signed with a domain certificate which has been moved to Trusted Publishers cert store.

The host computer, test@domain.com and current@domain.com have Allow Delegation set up in the domain and none of the users is marked as sensitive. The SeImpersonatePrivilege shouldn't be the problem either as Impersonation works.

When the client calls the service method the method returns "domain\current" and "Impersonation". What I require is "domain\current" and "Delegation". According to the second table at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx this would imply that the client or the service are not capable of delegation.

The domain has functional level of Windows 2000 Mixed. I read somewhere that this implies NTLM authentication but I believe that referred to the traffic between domain controllers. When not running on top of https Wireshark shows `supportedMech: 1.2.840.48018.1.2.2 (MS KRB5 - Microsoft Kerberos 5)` in the http response so it seems that Kerberos is enabled.

Technically we could raise the functional level up to Windows 2003 as the two Domain Controllers we have are both W2K3 servers but the IT department is currently unable to allocate resources to the backup operations and such which they want to do before they go and raise the functional level.

We do have a virtual test domain which could be upgraded to a functional level of Windows Server 2003, but this domain lacks certificate authority or client computers with IIS installed so while the functional level could be raised for testing purposes, setting up rest of the infrastructure is quite much work.

This is a problem I have been unable to solve for some time. Web seems to be full of "This is how you do it" kind of articles but I've not had any luck with these. Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the XBAP and the service on the same IIS host?

If I understand it correctly - you've got: client->XBAP->WCF.

The client is connecting to the XBAP hosted on IIS.  This may be authenticating via Kerberos and you seem to suggest it is.

The 2nd hop is then XBAP connecting to the WCF service.  If these two are hosted on the same IIS host, kerberos will not be attempted and NTLM will be used.  Kerberos will *only* be attempted if the WCF is on another host machine.

If you've got XBAP and WCF hosted on seperate boxes then you've got a classic kerberos over 2nd hop authentication setup and any of the "This is how you do it" kind of articles ought be explain it.

(I realise this question was some time ago - but I've only recently found it and only recently come to understand Kerberos and 2-hop issues.)

Comment: The underlying issue got resolved a while ago. The scenario here with XBAPs was supposed to be the simplest way to reproduce the lack of authentication so I've lost this setup and can't test what went wrong with it. Though now I'm curious on the XBAP hosted on IIS part: The origin of the XBAP matters, even for fully trusted XBAPs? I admit I've not looked too far into them but assumed they behaved like any stand alone .Net application when it came to networking.